# Just want choose some random elements of a list and return them in OCaml

Tags: list, random, functional-programming, ocaml

I want to choose `n` distinct random elements in a list `l` and return them in `choose_elements` but I have a `StackOverFlow` error for sufficiently large lists!

I tried to use a tail_recursive function `choose_elem_aux` in order to do that but I think my condition `List.mem` is not efficient enough in term of complexity!
I do this normally in other programming languages with a boolean mark array which I mark the index of each random number that is generated in `true`!
But I can't do this in OCaml because I can't do multiple instruction into an if or else block! like this:

```
... else {
mark[r] =true ;
choose_elem_aux l n mark tmp ;
} ...


let choose l = 
  nth l (Random.int (List.length l)) ;;
  
let rec choose_elem_aux l n tmp =
  if n=0 then tmp
  else
    let r=choose l in 
    if List.mem r tmp then
      choose_elem_aux l n tmp 
    else 
      choose_elem_aux l (n-1) (r::tmp) ;;

let rec choose_elements l n = 
  choose_elem_aux l n [] ;;
```

StackOverflow for large list like:

```
choose_elements [1...10_000] 7 ;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, ocaml does allow you to write several statements in an `if then else`, it's just not written as in C-like languages.

```ml
if condition then begin
  instruction1 ;
  instruction 2 ;
  (* ... *)
end
else begin
  (* ... *)
end
```

The `begin (* ... *) end` block works the same as parentheses, so you can also just parenthesise:

```ml
if condition then (
  instruction1 ;
  instruction 2 ;
  (* ... *)
)
else (
  (* ... *)
)
```

So you can do your optimisation just fine.

What happens here is that when writing `if b then t else f` in ocaml, you are building a value of type `T` if `t : T` and `f : T`.
You can for instance write `if b then 0 else 1` or `if b then "Hello" else "Goodbye"`.
It also works with the `unit` type (the type of most instructions):

```
if b then instruction1 else instruction2
```

The semicolon operator allows to do two instructions sequentially:

```
(;) : unit -> unit -> unit
```

Note that it is not the same as in most language where it marks the end of an instruction.

The problem is that when you write

```
if b then instruction1 else instruction2 ; instruction 3
```

it is not understood as

```
if b then instruction1 else (instruction2 ; instruction 3)
```

as you wished, but as

```
(if b then instruction1 else instruction2) ; instruction 3
```

which also makes sense because the `if` expression also has type `unit`.

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency I would suggest sorting the list *first* using a random int value from -1 to 1 and *then* selecting the first n elements from that sorted list.

```
let choose n l = 
  l 
  |> List.sort (fun _ _ -> Random.int 3 - 1) 
  |> List.to_seq 
  |> Seq.take n 
  |> List.of_seq
```

If you need them randomly selected *but* in the same order they were in initially, you can map indexes onto them in the form of tuples, sort randomly, select them, and then re-sort based on the indexes. Finally, you would use `List.map` to discard the no longer needed indexes.

```
let choose n l = 
  l 
  |> List.mapi (fun i x -> (i, x))
  |> List.sort (fun _ _ -> Random.int 3 - 1) 
  |> List.to_seq 
  |> Seq.take n 
  |> List.of_seq
  |> List.sort (fun (i, _) (j, _) -> compare i j)
  |> List.map snd
```

### Complexity

What you're doing is like picking cards randomly from a 52 card deck and checking to see if it's one you've already drawn, then putting the card back into the deck and drawing again.

Not only might this result in numerous pointless draws as you draw the same card again and again, but each time you run your function you're A. iterating over the entire list to find its length, and B. iterating over your entire results accumulator to determine whether you've already drawn a card.

This yields an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, which scales poorly for large samples.

Sorting can be done in O(n * log n) complexity, and everything else involved has linear runtime complexity, so the sort first approach scales much better. For instance, 10,000 squared is *100,000,000*, but 10,000 times log<sub>2</sub>10,000 is approximately *130,000*.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @théo-winterhalter
I just to it in this way:

```ml
let rec choose_elem_aux l n mark tmp =
  if n = 0 then 
    tmp
  else
    let r = Random.int (length l) in 
    if mark.(r) then
      choose_elem_aux l n mark tmp 
    else (
      mark.(r) <- true;
      choose_elem_aux l (n-1) mark ((nth l r)::tmp);
    );;

let rec choose_elements l n = 
  let mark = Array.make (length l) false in
  choose_elem_aux l n mark [];;
```